# export data to multiple excel files based on dates python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, date, export-to-excel

I'm trying to export my datasets to multiple excel files based on dates.

Here's my table

```
datestart
+----------+
2019-03-14
2019-03-14
2019-03-12
2019-03-11
2019-03-08
2019-03-07
2019-03-06
2019-03-05
2019-03-04
2019-03-01
```

for each date I want to create a new file.

```
datestart   | filename
+-----------+-------------+
2019-03-14  | file_031419
2019-03-14  | file_031419
2019-03-12  | file_031219
2019-03-12  | file_031219
2019-03-08  | file_030819
2019-03-08  | file_030819
2019-03-06  | file_030619
2019-03-06  | file_030619
2019-03-06  | file_030619
2019-03-01  | file_030119
```

The dates are stored as datetime. I don't want to hard code the dates. I want the script to look for columns with the same date, group them together and export to a file with the date in the filename.

The script should export to 5 files. Each of the files would only include data with the specific date.

For example, file_031419 would only have the data with 031419 as the date, file_031219 would only have 031219 data, etc..

file_031419
file_031219
file_030819
file_030619
file_030119

Comment: How are your dates stored? Are they strings?

Comment: And what is your problem? Please be more precise. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of unique dates using `list(set())`, use Pandas and `df.loc[]` to subset the data based on the date, use `pd.to_datetime()` to convert the date into the format you want for the filename, and then use `df.to_excel()` to save your datasets as Excel files:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.Series('''2019-03-14
2019-03-14
2019-03-12
2019-03-12
2019-03-08
2019-03-08
2019-03-06
2019-03-06
2019-03-06
2019-03-01'''.split('\n'), name='datestart', dtype=str).to_frame()

df['data'] = np.random.rand(len(df))

# Get unique dates
dates = list(set(df.datestart.values))

for date in dates:
    idx = df.datestart == date # Filter by unique date
    filename = 'file_'+list(set(pd.to_datetime(df.loc[idx, 'datestart']).dt.strftime('%m%d%y')))[0]+'.xlsx'
    df.loc[idx, 'data'].to_excel(filename) # Save subset of data frame as excel file
```

Comment: I don't want to hard code the dates. I want the script to look for columns with the same date, group them together and export to a separate file from all other dates.

Comment: Okay, that changes the question. You should put those additional details in your question, and I will update my answer to reflect them.

Comment: This only exports one file with the first date in the list. I would need 5 files. The 5 files would include all the data with the specific date.file_031419
file_031219
file_030819
file_030619
file_030119

Answer (score 0):

You can use some string methods and string formatting.

```
dates = [‘2019-03-01’, ‘2019-05-06’]
for date in dates:
    split_date = date.split(‘-‘)
    fname = ‘file_{}{}{}’.format(split_date[0],split_date[2],split_date[1]
    # save to .csv with fname
```